# GoLand debugger | Attach to process | Access is denied to dlv.exe

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, jetbrains-ide, goland, delve

I am using GoLand to debug a process built using `go build`. <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F5</kbd>. But I am getting this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\GoLand 2022.1.4\plugins\go\lib\dlv\windows\dlv.exe" --listen=127.0.0.1:56356 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false attach 3064 --
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:56356
could not attach to pid 3064: Access is denied.
```

I ran GoLand in administrator mode, I have given `dlv.exe` administrator privileges. I also tried running GoLand in elevated privilege mode but still got the same problem.

I tried debugging in Visual Studio Code (by running VSCode in administrator mode) and I am able to debug the process by using below `launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "local",
            "processId": 13932
        }
    ]
}
```

I like GoLand debugger more. Any suggestions on how to fix the issue in GoLand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be resolved in newer versions of GoLand. Please try [GoLand 2023.1 (or later)](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/other.html) and use *Help->Contact Support* or *Help->Submit a Bug Report* if the problem persists.

Comment: Indeed with newer version it got solved